# Issues with 301 error in invokehttp processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use invokeHttp to send request to this API.

http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03478891?displayxml=true

However, I got the 301 moved permanently error code. In the configuration of the invokehttp, I just set the "Remote URL" property, others are default. How can I fix that?

Do I need add a SSL context service? My nifi version is 1.11.4.

Here is the configuration in my invokehttp.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The web page doesn't use SSL (it is `http` not `https`), so you don't need an SSL context service. What is `Follow Redirects` set to in the InvokeHTTP processor? Please include your NiFi version & InvokeHTTP config

Comment: @Sdairs I edited my post. I just set the URL, other properties are default. This web page also can be opened with https.

Comment: Looks like the non-https url forces a redirect to https - so you'd be better off using the https url